# Cant set proper margins for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created CollectionView and its cell in storyboards, I try to set cell size and margins through UICollectionViewFlowLayout in code but no matter what I do margins don't change. Changing size in storyboards also doesn't change anything
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mN9H.jpg).
I'm always getting these margins:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxrq5.jpg)
What am I doing wrong?

```swift
 let itemsPerRow = 1
 let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)

extension VideoVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left + sectionInsets.right
        let widthPerItem = collectionView.bounds.width - paddingSpace

        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: 265)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return sectionInsets
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 5
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the collectionView.contentInset? = UIEdgeInsets() ? You then also need to set the collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets

Comment: it doesn't help, the problem is that the width of the cell doesn't change no matter what I return in sizeForItemAt method, however the height changes properly. Maybe I messed up with constraints in storyboards?

Comment: Ah okay I hadn't understood your problem properly. You will not see a difference if your paddingSpace is only 2 points.

Comment: No matter what padding I set, it doesn't affect anything, that is the problem.